# Dificuldades com o Dll import C#

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, import

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em reescrever um método de uma dll em C#, compramos um verificador de preços de um fabricante, no caso ele fornece uma dll e um código de exemplo em Delphi.

Essa dll possui algumas funções entre elas iniciar o serviço com o leitor, fazer a leitura dos dados, verificar quais equipamentos estão conectados, etc. No caso quero transformar esse método:

```
function bReceiveBarcode(var stAddress; var BarCode: PChar): Boolean; 
stdcall;
```

Em um método disponível no C#, por isso tentei criar esse método:

```
[DllImport("VP.dll", EntryPoint = "bReceiveBarcode")]
private static extern Boolean bReceiveBarcode(ref stAddress, ref string barcode);
```

No caso stAddress é uma struct, estou tentando usar esse método na minha aplicação, mas aparece o erro `Identificador esperando` é como se o primeiro parâmetro estivesse errado.

Comment: tem que ter um tipo no parâmetro... `ref stAddress` tente `ref object stAddress`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> é como se o primeiro parâmetro estivesse errado.

Ele está errado, você precisa definir o tipo do parâmetro.

```
[DllImport("VP.dll", EntryPoint = "bReceiveBarcode")]
private static extern Boolean bReceiveBarcode(ref object stAddress, ref string barcode);
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas agora estou tentando utilizar esse método, mas aparece que os argumentos 1 e argumento 2 não dever ser transmitido com a palavra-chave ref.

stBarcode é uma variável da struct stAddress e barcode é uma variável string, tentei fazer com que elas recebessem o valor por referência. Também tentei colocar ref antes dos argumentos, mas não deu certo.

    if (bReceiveBarcode(stBarcode, barcode))
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Número do código de barras:" + barcode);
    }

Comment: @FlávioNavesJr Se o problema desta pergunta foi resolvido, abra uma nova pergunta com o novo problema. Assim mantemos o site organizado. Aliás, você se a resposta te ajudou você pode marcá-la como correta usando o **✓** do lado esquerdo da resposta.